# Converting a width of PX to % but keep the text contents in ratio

Tags: javascript, php, css, math

I have a 'design tool' where users can adjust the css properties to create something like this:

[image]

This then saves in the DB the CSS properties.

The width of the white div is 300px. What I know want to do is on my home page loop through these DB rows and display the designs EXACTLY how they were first designed. The issue is, to keep my website responsive and generally make things easier in the future when adding more white div sizes I want too...

Make them display at 25% (or 50% / 100% down smaller screens) BUT I want the text to stay the same in ratio. So the word wrap is the same and the line height etc. All values are stored in em, but going to a percentage causes the words to wrap incorrectly (as you can imagine).

Here is the example at 25%:

[image]

Can I do any clever maths etc to adjust the font size / line height to keep it the same no matter what percentage width I make the container?

For reference the items are looped through and displayed like this:

```
<a href="/design/create?canvas-size={{ $order->canvas_size }}&design-text={{ $order->design_text }}&font-size={{ $order->font_size }}&line-height={{ $order->line_height }}&add-border={{ $order->border }}">
<div class="design-canvas order-item" id="canvas-size-{{ $order->canvas_size }}">

    <div class="designText"
         style="font-size: {{ $order->font_size }}em; line-height: {{ $order->line_height }}em; border: {{ $order->border }}">
        {{ $order->design_text }}
    </div>

  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: You're entering dangerous territory here. First, you won't be able to do this portably in CSS; you'll need JavaScript to take the brunt of the load. You may also have issues with font size differences on the viewer's device (including mobile devices!) and screen sizes (again thinking mobile users).

Comment: How about letting the div think that it is always the same width, but then using the CSS `scale` property to display it at the desired size.

Answer (score 0):

Making text that scales is not possible with the current CSS specification, but you could use JavaScript. Have you tried looking at the library called [FitText.js](http://fittextjs.com/)? It does the scaling work for you. (Give it a shot, and resize the window to watch the font scale up and down according to its width).

After adding the library, you'd have to use a little bit of JQuery. Example:

```
$(".designText").fitText(1.2);
```

If you want the font smaller, you could increase the `fitText()` value above 1, or if you want it larger, you could decrease it below 1.